# How to get started with the gmail-ruby-api gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, gmail-api

I working with Gmail using the [Gmail for Ruby](https://github.com/jhk753/gmail-ruby-api) gem, but can't figure out how to get started with it.

The documentation say: I could do something like:

```
require "gmail"

Gmail.client_id = "...Your app client id..."
Gmail.client_secret = "…app secret…"
Gmail.refresh_token = "...refresh token…"

Gmail::Message.all
```

But then I got this error:

```
undefined method `client_id=' for Gmail:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I also tried initializing it like this:

```
require 'Gmail'

Gmail.new

Gmail.client_id = "...Your app client id..."
Gmail.client_secret = "…app secret…"
Gmail.refresh_token = "...refresh token…"

Gmail::Message.all
```

But then got:

```
`initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3) (ArgumentError)
```

I can't tell what arguments it's looking for.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: I'm trying it out outside of my project to first make sure I can get it going. So I just installed the gem using `gem install gmail-api-ruby`. Then I ran the above code from a test ruby file.

Comment: honestly, i would just find a different gem. this one seems old and out of date and incomplete. there's a [more official gem here](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)

Comment: yeah, I was working off the official gem, but found that everything I was already doing had already been done in this other gem

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm also looking at the same GEM and wanted a quick start on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby) for a sample simple Ruby command-line application that makes requests to the Gmail API..

> **Installing the google-api-client gem**
>
> If you haven't installed the Google API Client Library for Ruby before, open a terminal and install using `RubyGems`:
>
> `$ gem install google-api-client`
>
> If you already have the gem installed and would simply like to update to the latest version:
>
> `$ gem update -y google-api-client`
>
> Depending on your system, you may need to prepend these commands with `sudo`.

Be sure to check the extensive [Getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/start/get_started) for a quick overview of how to make your first request.

Comment: I already have the official api gem working. I was just hoping to get the gmail-ruby-api gem working rather than recreating what had already been done.